# EC2 events/maintenance/ key

Tags: amazon-ec2, metadata

Recently I've started seeing some instances with the metadata key http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/events/maintenance/ but most of the instances I manage do not have this key. I believe it's new but I have no proof either way.

Anyone have more info about this?

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue as well, SaltStack is affected by this (while building grains).
The endpoint previously was available only when a maintenance was scheduled.

I was able to confirm through support that this URI is now always available. Support was not sure if this was intentional or a bug. But this affects us-east-1 (for some use cases like mine with Salt) for now and will possibly affect other regions in future if they decide to roll it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes this is exactly where I first saw this issue - it broke our Salt grains as well. I talked to AWS support too, they confirmed that it was a newly added key but could not offer more information than that.